# R package build fails trying to locate temporary file

Tags: r, emacs, devtools

I'm working on a private package for work and am using `devtools` to soothe the process.

I've just gone to `build()` the package again and it fails with the error...

```
> getwd()
/mnt/work/project/lib
> build()
'/usr/lib64/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD build '/mnt/work/project/lib'  \
  --no-resave-data --no-manual 

* checking for file '/mnt/work/project/lib/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
cp: cannot stat 'lib/data-raw/.#import.R': No such file or directory
 ERROR
copying to build directory failed
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I do have the file `lib/data-raw/import.R` (it reads in my raw data and saves to `data/` for lazy loading) and at some point Emacs created `lib/data-raw/#import.R#` and I suspect I used `build()` whilst this was still there around but I've since deleted it and can't work out how to stop `build()` looking for it when called.

Advice on how to purge `lib/data-raw/.#import.R' from being included in the build would be very much appreciated.